# How to make class act like super in find method

Tags: python

I have searched around for an answer to this and I suspect I am not understanding some fundamental concepts.

I have a class:

```
class Motif(str):
    def __init__(self, s):
        str.__init__(self, s)
        self.motif = s.upper()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.motif

    def __str__(self):
        return self.motif
```

Example usage:

```
>>> m = Motif("gtca")
>>> print m  
GTCA
```

I want to be able to search through a string using this instance of `Motif` and find any matches.

```
>>> s = 'GTAGGCTGAGTCATTHAGTCAT'
>>> s.find(m)  
9
```

Is someone able to point me in the right direction here?

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Is it required to be a separate class, e.g. are you defining any new methods on the class?

Comment: Yes I have a couple of methods defined for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is basically an initializer, it's not a constructor. The object construction happens in [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method. Hence if you want to store uppercase version of the string passed you should override `__new__`.

```
class Motif(str):
    def __new__(cls, s):
        return super(Motif, cls).__new__(cls, s.upper())
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> m = Motif("gtca")
>>> m
'GTCA'
>>> s = 'GTAGGCTGAGTCATTHAGTCAT'
>>> s.find(m)
9
```